Book about a planet where women live in "Wells" until they become pregnant, then become the property of the man who impregnated them
Planet of low fertility, women live in "Wells" until they become pregnant, then become the property of the man who impregnated them.  Woman who "runs" the Well in the story, comes of age, discovers through video left by deceased mother, her father is a god & sets out to find him. If I remember right, with training, she develops some power of her own but ends up in conflict with her father.
This book will be decades old!  Can't remember exactly when I read it but guessing when I was in my 20's and I am 74!!

Maybe one of the books by Joanna Russ?

Thank you for the suggestion. Looked up her work, nothing in the book descriptions or reviews matches up to the book i am looking for.

FOUND IT!!!   High Couch of Silistra by Janet Morris

Thanks for sharing, how did you find the name of the book?
